# Having problems with register page & changing the SQL to where there is an ID

Tags: php, mysql, auto-increment

I recently installed Jpmaster77's log in script. I have to say, it is fantastic, but I am having trouble making some modifications. To start off, my problem is mainly adding an ID with an auto increment that increases 1 by 1, so instead of users having just a username to go by, they have an ID that matches them. I am doing this for many reasons, one being so if users change their username I can still find them. To start off, here is my main problem:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
 username varchar(30) primary key,
 password varchar(32),
 userid varchar(32),
 userlevel tinyint(1) unsigned not null,
 email varchar(50),
 timestamp int(11) unsigned not null
);
```

I tried creating another row above username labeled "ID" with an auto increment, however according to PHPMyAdmin, I can not have something be primary and have an auto increment on two different rows. This is conflicting, and no matter what I do, it messes up the registration. Everytime I try to register with just the slightest change to the database I get this error "We're sorry, but an error has occurred and your registration for the username ******** could not be completed.Please try again at a later time."

I have spent the past hour trying to find the problem and I have no idea what it could be. If anyone could lead me in the right direction i'd be very happy. I have also decided to post register.php to help with this problem: http://pastebin.com/c5S0SDcc

Comment: If username is the primary key, ID cannot also be the primary key. Make username not the primary key and make tables reference users on ID not username.

Comment: I tried taking out primary key from username and then making an auto increment on the id and it didn't work, i got the error when trying to register.

Comment: You can't change the structure of your table without changing how your code interacts with it. The table schema is just another kind of code, in a sense.

Comment: I already know that -_- I am trying to find out how to change it to where it works.

Comment: The code you've posted is not the problematic code - all it does is inform the user that there has been an issue. You need to look elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

How about if you change your username-field to be an unique key -field that means, two rows cannot have same username, which is the case also in primary key fields. This should not break your php-code.

```
CREATE TABLE users (
 id int unsigned auto_increment,
 username varchar(30),
 password varchar(32),
 userid varchar(32),
 userlevel tinyint(1) unsigned not null,
 email varchar(50),
 timestamp int(11) unsigned not null,
 unique key(username),
 primary key (id)
);
```

**Edit:**

Ok, if you change your database schema you must change also the other code to match the database schema. I.e. in this case you must change the function that inserts user into the database. Let me explain how I debugged this.

1) You didin't provide the full source code so I googled for Jpmaster77 and I found [this site](https://github.com/ivannovak/jpmaster77-s-Login-System-)

2) I realized you are trying to register into the system and I opened register.php file and I searched the term

> We're sorry, but an error has occurred

and I found the correct line and saw that $_SESSION['regsuccess'] is set but it is set to false.

3) Then I opened the process.php file and saw that in the procRegister-function is the line that calls the `$session->register` function and it returns 2 in this case because registration is not successful.

4) Then I had to know what the `$session->register-function` does. I opened `session.php` file from the include-directory and searched the `register`-function. I know that this function returns 2 in this case. So I found the `return 2;` from line 233 that has a comment

> Registration attempt failed

5) If that function returns 2 it must be because `$database->addNewUser` function returns false. Again, I opened the `database.php` file from the include-directory and looked to the `addNewUser`-function.

6) So here this function returns false. And the reason is obvious:

The script tries to insert a row into the database without giving column names inside the insert query. So if you change the table column order and add or remove columns, like in this case, that script will fail. Like MySQL's documentation says:

> If you do not specify a list of column names for INSERT ... VALUES or
>   INSERT ... SELECT, values for every column in the table must be
>   provided by the VALUES list

You can try to fix this by giving column names to the insert query, but it is **not recommended** if you don't know what you are doing.

```
$q = sprintf("INSERT INTO ".TBL_USERS." (username, password, userid, userlevel, email, name) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', $time, '0', '%s', '0', '0')",
            mysql_real_escape_string($username),
            mysql_real_escape_string($password),
            mysql_real_escape_string($userid),
            mysql_real_escape_string($ulevel),
            mysql_real_escape_string($email),
            mysql_real_escape_string($name));
```

I hope this post helps you find out problemes and to debug your scripts.

Comment: I tried this, unfortunately I still get this error "We're sorry, but an error has occurred and your registration for the username achilles, could not be completed.
Please try again at a later time." Now It has something to do with this code... http://pastebin.com/LRAiHkC5

Comment: The error message us not coming from sql server. Please provide the source code of the $session -> register function.

Comment: No it is not. In line 15 your code calls  $session->register -function which returns 1 or 2 so perhaps your error message comes from that function